# SecureString usage

Tags: c#, winforms

One article was using SecureString text box control (http://weblogs.asp.net/pglavich/440191 btw. is it good class?). Then to get the string value, it had such code:

```
using (Crypto cryptor = new Crypto())
{
 IntPtr ptr = Marshal.SecureStringToBSTR(password);
 this.password = cryptor.EncryptString(Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(ptr)); 
 Marshal.ZeroFreeBSTR(ptr);
}
```

- When asked that `Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(ptr)` also creates a string (which should
  not be secure), author replied that it is inside `using` and the `string` should
  be there for say one second-and then get destroyed. My question is, is it true? I thought `using` keyword
  applies only to the Crypto object, isn't it? Why it applies to string?
- Finally, assume I use that `SecureString` text box control. And assume I have
  some security helper method, like `Encrypt(string password, byte[] data)`, or even `Encrypt(byte [] key, byte [] data)`, what is the secure way to pass that secure string(or secure string contents?) to that Encrypt method?

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, is it true? I thought `using` keyword applies only to the Crypto object, isn't it? Why it applies to string?

That's correct: it doesn't apply to type `string`.

`using` just means that `cryptor.Dispose()` will be called once the `using` block is left, but `cryptor` has absolutely no way whatsoever to modify any `string` object, nor should it: that isn't its job.

> Finally, assume I use that `SecureString` text box control. And assume I have some security helper method, like `Encrypt(string password, byte[] data)`, or even `Encrypt(byte [] key, byte [] data)`, what is the secure way to pass that secure string(or secure string contents?) to that Encrypt method?

With an `Encrypt(string password, byte[] data)` method, that is impossible. The `string` object's contents cannot be overwritten, because strings are immutable, so the password cannot be cleared from memory before the string is garbage-collected. And once the string *is* garbage-collected, the memory still doesn't get cleared, and you no longer know what memory it is you need to clear.

With a `Encrypt(byte[] key, byte[] data)`, it is possible.

You'd first have to pin the array (*before* you fill its contents), so that the garbage collector cannot move it around in memory. There's [`GCHandle.Alloc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1246yz8f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you can use for that. Make sure you pass `GCHandleType.Pinned`. This makes sure the key only exists in a single location in memory.

This is something you can safely pass to the `Encrypt` method.

Then, after you're done with that key, you can re-set all bytes in that array to zero. Since the array is still pinned, you can then be certain that the key doesn't exist elsewhere in the process memory.

Finally, don't forget to call [`gcHandle.Free()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle.free%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to prevent your array from hanging around forever.

Note: there are also other safe ways of dealing with `SecureString`, but they involve pointers, and are not an option for the two specific `Encrypt` signatures you've given.

Note 2: the underlying assumption of this answer, as well as `SecureString` in general, is that the time the password is kept in memory un-encrypted should be minimised. A crash dump when the code is not dealing with any password should not reveal any password. There are also other valid concerns that are not addressed by `SecureString`: a malicious program on your own computer can obviously inject code into your process to decrypt strings exactly the same way your own process would. This is not a problem `SecureString` is designed to solve, nor do I claim that what I describe in this answer solves it.

Comment: @hvd: What are the assumptions that it makes that might cause it not to work out of interest?

Comment: @Chris It assumes that the pointer returned by `GCHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject()` points to the first character in the string, but the documentation for neither `AddrOfPinnedObject` nor `string` supports that, even if it is currently true. It also assumes that `new string(...)` actually creates a new object, but the CLR may have (and does have) optimisations where the same `string` instance gets re-used (and those optimisations are valid since strings are supposed to be immutable).